# Which is the Spring equivalent for the CDI @Produces annotation?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, cdi

When I was working with CDI, I could use the [`@Produces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Produces.html) annotation to create a producer method to be called to choose which bean that implemented an interface would be injected by the `@Inject` annotation .

Now I am working with Spring, but I didn't find anything similar. What I need to use to achieve the same result I had with the `@Produces` annotation in CDI when I use the `@Autowired` annotation?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're looking for [`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html):

> @Bean is a method-level annotation and a direct analog of the XML `<bean/>` element. The annotation supports most of the attributes offered by `<bean/>`, such as: init-method, destroy-method, autowiring, lazy-init, dependency-check, depends-on and scope.

Example (taken from link above):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    //similar to @Produces CDI annotation
    @Bean
    public TransferService transferService() {
        return new TransferServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

I suggest you to pay a read to this: [Spring DI and CDI comparative study](http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/01/11/spring-di-and-cdi-comparative-study/)

Comment: Beware of one major difference - a CDI producer has access to InjectionPoint, which allows it to do some additional tricks.

Comment: You can also use @Autowired for passing elements that need to be injected in the bean and set them.

Comment: With CDI it's possible to inject primitive types or objects that are not beans themselves. Is that also valid with Spring? Also when I got this right, the concepts are different: while CDI allows for every bean to produce an injectable object, in Spring only classes annotated with @Configuration can produce Beans (otherwise in Lite mode). The intentions are different...

Comment: @Wecherowski Spring does allow you to inject primitive types using [`@Value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html).