# Injecting properties in Spring using CDI fails due BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, cdi

I am trying to inject properties file into my spring component using CdI and keeps throwing the exception below.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.Properties ValidationService.ProjectProperties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @PropertiesFromFile(value=config.properties)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
```

Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class ValidationService {
    @Autowired
    @PropertiesFromFile("config.properties")
    private Properties configProperties;

    @Autowired
    @PropertiesFromFile("custom.properties")
    private Properties customProperties;
}
```

Another piece of code that I tried was:

```
@Component
public class ValidationService {
    @Inject
    @PropertiesFromFile("config.properties")
    private Properties configProperties;

    @Inject
    @PropertiesFromFile("custom.properties")
    private Properties customProperties;
}
```

Although Spring now supports Inject under AutoWired I still tried both.

I am new to Spring, I would really appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction

P.S. The code for the Generic annotation can be found here:
http://slackspace.de/articles/injecting-properties-in-java-ee-applications/

Comment: Do you have the Producer method configured with the @PropertiesFromFile in your project as mentioned in the link you provided?

From your error log, it seems it is not able to find the producer method with the PropertiesFromFile qualifier.

Comment: @Manish I copy-pasted everything that was in the link provided. Is there anything else that I need to make this work?

Comment: Nick - Sorry for the late answer. I think there might be a problem with the Producer method. Can you please look into this link, and see if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876402/which-is-the-spring-equivalent-for-the-cdi-produces-annotation - The answer describes an equivalent for @Produces in Spring beans,

Comment: @Manish Dont worry about it, ill read the link that youve sent me, Thanks a lot,